# arrays VB.NET vs c

Tags: c, vb.net, arrays

just a sanity check please:

in VB.NET:

dim myarray(5) as integer

gives six elements 0 to 5

but in c?

int myarray[5];

gives five elements 0 to 4 ?

is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's correct!

Hope I saved your sanity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. VB.NET does this for the benefit of those "programmers" who can't think in terms of zero-based indexing. Element 0 is there, but you're free to ignore it if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET array enumeration starts with 1

Comment: And this ( http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF ) is why I hate VB.